# Add custom role across network in multisite

Tags: user-roles

Maybe this is a duplicate of [Add role across network in multisite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102368/add-role-across-network-in-multisite), but the answers there are not conclusive so I'm asking again. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

I'm trying to add two new custom roles on a multisite installation. I have written a plugin, installed it and enabled it across the whole network, and the new roles are added by this plugin's activation hook.

There, I simply do

```
add_role('x', 'Description of X', $capabilities_array);
add_role('y', 'Description of Y', $capabilities_array);
```

Then, I try to create a new "child" site, add a new user to it, and then apply one of the custom roles to that new user. The custom role appears at the roles dropdown list, but when I try to apply the role to the user, I get an error saying "You can't give users that role".

I searched a lot over the internet and found that the roles and capabilities are stored under the user_roles option in the options table. However, I noticed only the options table of the root site has the custom roles I added. I suspect this is the cause of the error I get.

But then, how do I go around this? Is there a way of creating new custom roles which are visible and can be applied to every "child" site, even to the new ones I possibly add in the  future?

My ultimate intention is to customize the dashboard and menu options of each site/user based on its custom role.

Ideally, I'm looking for a solution without any extra plugins involved, as this is going to be part of a services platform I'm willing to provide.

Thanks in advance.
Arnaldo

Comment: For anyone who's searching for a solution: take a look at "Must Use Plugins" pointed out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722552/multisite-custom-roles-applied-by-default